# Transpose dataset and counting occurrences

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

The original dataset contains survey data in long form

**Original dataset**

```
T Q1  Q2  Q3    
M1 3 5 4  
M1 3 1 3  
M1 1 3 1  
M2 4 4 2  
M2 2 2 3  
M2 5 5 5
```

Where *T* is the type of respondents and *Q1--Q3* are the questions, and the cell value corresponds to their agreement level on a *1--5* Likert 
scale.

**Wanted dataset**

```
T Q A1 A2 A3 A4 A5  
M1 Q1 1 0 3 0 0  
M2 Q1 0 1 0 1 1  
M1 Q2 1 0 1 0 1  
M2 Q2 0 1 0 1 1  
M1 Q3 1 0 1 1 0  
M2 Q3 0 1 1 0 1
```

Where *A1--A5* are the possible answers (1--5 Likert) and the cell value contains the frequency of these answers for each group M1 and M2.

How to get from the *Original dataset* to the *Wanted dataset*?

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. Could you please finish the sentence?

Comment: `reshape2::recast(df, Type + variable ~ paste0("A",value), id.var = "Type")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use the dplyr and tidyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Type = c('M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2'),
           Q1 = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5),
           Q2 = c(5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5),
           Q3 = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5))

df %>%
  gather(key = 'Q', value = 'A', -Type) %>%
  group_by(Type, Q, A) %>%
  summarize(Count = n()) %>%
  mutate(A = paste0('A', A)) %>%
  spread(key = A, value = Count, fill = 0) %>%
  arrange(Q, Type)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `tidyverse` fuction to solve your problem. Notice that I had to create row identifiers because not always gather an spread are symmetrics (for more, check [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/426) out)

```
library(tidyverse)

# Data
x <- data.frame(
  T = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M2"),
  Q1 = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5),
  Q2 = c(5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5),
  Q3 = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5)
)


# Modification
gather(x, key, A, -T) %>%
  group_by(T, key, A) %>%
  mutate(row_id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(A, A, fill = 0, sep = "") %>%
  select(-row_id)
```